# nopCommerce View Modification with JS and CSS only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, nopcommerce

I need to modify the look of product page for few of the products.
I can only add/modify JS and CSS files and not the original codes.

Current Render HTML is like below:

```
<dt>
   <label class="text-prompt">
     Spherical Right
   </label>
</dt>
<dd>
  <select name="product_attribute_115_19_25" id="product_attribute_115_19_25">
    <option value="0">---</option>
    <option value="64">1</option>
    <option value="65">2</option>
  </select>
</dd>
<dt>
   <label class="text-prompt">
     Spherical Left
   </label>
</dt>
<dd>
  <select name="product_attribute_115_19_24" id="product_attribute_115_19_24">
    <option value="0">---</option>
    <option value="66">1</option>
    <option value="67">2</option>
  </select>
</dd>
<dt>
  <label class="text-prompt">
     Cy Right
  </label>
</dt>
<dd>
  <select name="product_attribute_115_19_27" id="product_attribute_115_19_27">
    <option value="0">---</option>
  </select>
</dd>
<dt>
   <label class="text-prompt">
      Cy Left
   </label>
</dt>
<dd>
  <select name="product_attribute_115_18_28" id="product_attribute_115_18_28">
     <option value="0">---</option>
  </select>
</dd>
```

And the output is like:

[image]

What I am looking for is something like a table format as given below:

[image]

Is it possible to modify the look just by applying JS, given that, I can rename Text of the fields to identify the tags based on the contents?